# Dynamic buttons in table layout adding Horizontally

Tags: android, android-button, android-tablelayout

I'm trying to add buttons in Table layout.
Initially I will have a single row with a single button.
When the user clicks that button, It should create 2 dynamic buttons in the next row 'Horizontally'.

But with my code, I'm getting vertically dynamic buttons Instead of horizontally.

```
while(id <rowcount+2)
{

tr = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
table.addView(tr);

Button btn1 = new Button(MainActivity.this);
btn1.setText("");
btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
btn1.setId(id);
tr.addView(btn1);   
id++;   

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are creating new object of TableRow each time, TableRow represents elements in Horizontal and TableLayout represent data in Vertical that's why you getting Buttons in Vertical manner

```
tr = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
while(id <rowcount+2)
{
Button btn1 = new Button(MainActivity.this);
btn1.setText("");
btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
btn1.setId(id);
tr.addView(btn1);   
id++;   
}
table.addView(tr);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are creating a new row each time for the loop
try this.

```
    tr = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);

    while(id <rowcount+2) {
      Button btn1 = new Button(MainActivity.this);
      btn1.setText("");
      btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
      btn1.setId(id);
      tr.addView(btn1);   
      id++;   
    }
   table.addView(tr);
```